# Can I add a new value in the braces (permutation) inside a bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash, permutation, expansion

I would like to add a new value to a list that is inside of an array element.
Is there an easy way to do that?

I don't think this is an associative array.  I tried to updated the element as if it were and I get an error message stating "cannot assign list to array member".

```
temparr=( d{a,e,i,o,u} )
temparr[d]+=("y")
echo "${temparr[@]}"
```

I'm hoping to see this in the output:

```
da de di do du dy
```

Comment: Your array just contains `da de di do du` and is entirely identical to you doing `temparr=(da de di do du)`. The fact that your array elements were at some point generated through brace expansion by appending things to the string `d` is not retained in any form, so there's no way to affect that generation after the fact.

Comment: For example, use a function that you pass to "y" and it will add "dy" to your array.

Answer (score 2):

You can add elements same way you have populated it initially:

```
temparr+=(d{y,z})
```

This will give:

```
declare -p temparr
```

```
declare -a temparr=([0]="da" [1]="de" [2]="di" [3]="do" [4]="du" [5]="dy" [6]="dz")
```

Your attempt will generate a syntax error:

```
temparr[d]+=("y")
bash: temparr[d]: cannot assign list to array member
```

Because your array is not an associative array and it is indexed by array positions 0,1,2,3,, only.